# How to return output on the same page ajax php

Tags: php, ajax

I want to organize the selection query from index.php to action, so i can be able to call the file with ajax to show the data on the page.(index.php). So, the activity I want to do is to able to submit data of the form to the database and to display result on the same page(index.php) without refreshing the page. Help please

```
Here's my files
1.action.php
2.index.php
3.maker.js
```

//-----------------------action.php-----------------------------

```
<?php
include ("db_connect.php"); // Connecting to the database
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];
$ParentId = $_REQUEST['ParentId'];
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];  

if ($action=="add")
{
    $query="INSERT into `comments` VALUES (NULL,'{$ParentId}','{$user}','{$text}',NOW())";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}

if ($action=="delete")
{   
    $delete = "DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE id=$text";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$delete);
}
?>
```

//index.php

```
<div id="table_content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="maker.js">
<?php
function ShowForm($AnswerCommentId) 
{  ?> 
<form id="myForm">  
<input type="hidden"  name="comment_on" id="comment_on"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php print md5($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" />
<input id="user" name="user" value="name" autocomplete="off" onfocus="if(this.value == 'name'){this.value = ''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'name'}"/>               
<textarea id='text' name='text' value="comment" onfocus="if(this.value == 'comment'){this.value = ''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'comment'}" ></Textarea>       
<input id="ParentId" name="ParentId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($AnswerCommentId);?>"/>
<button type='button' OnClick=SendComment()>Comment</button>
</form>
<?php
}

$query="SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if (isset($_REQUEST['AnswerId']))
{ $AnswerId = $_REQUEST['AnswerId'];    }
else
{ $AnswerId = 0; }

$i=0;
while ($mytablerow = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
$mytable[$i] = $mytablerow; 
$i++;   
}

function tree($treeArray, $level, $pid = 0) 
{
global $AnswerId;

if (! $treeArray) 
{ return; } 

foreach($treeArray as $item){
    if ($item[1] == $pid)       
    {
        ?>  
<div class="CommentWithReplyDiv" style="margin-left:<?php echo($level*60);?>px">    
        <div class="CommentDiv">
        <pre class="Message"><?php echo($item[3]) ; ?></pre>
        <div class="User"><?php echo($item[2]) ; ?></div>
        <div class="Date"><?php echo($item[4]) ; ?></div>
        <?php               
if ($level<=4)  { echo '<a href="" class="ReplyLink" onclick="AnswerComment('.$item[0].');return false;">Reply</a>'; }
         echo '<a href="" class="DeleteLink" onclick="DeleteComment('.$item[0].');return false;">Delete</a>';
        ?> </div> <?php

        if ($AnswerId == $item[0])
        {
        ?><div id="InnerDiv"><?php  ShowForm($AnswerId);  ?></div>
<?php   
        } 
        ?> </div> <?php 

        tree($treeArray, $level+1, $item[0]);   // Recursion
    }       
}
}
tree($mytable, 0);
?>
```

//maker.js

```
function DeleteComment(number){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",                  
    data: "user=1"+"&text="+number+"&ParentId=1"+"&action=delete",                  
    success: function(html){                        
        $("#table_content").html(html);         
       }
 });
}

function AnswerComment (id){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",                   
    data: "AnswerId="+id,                   
    success: function(html){                        
        $("#table_content").html(html);             
       }
});     
}

function SendComment (){
var user1 = $("#user").val();
var text1  = $("#text").val();  
var ParentId1  = $("#ParentId").val() + ""; 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",  
    cache: false,       
    data: "user="+user1+"&text="+text1+"&ParentId="+ParentId1+"&action=add",        
    success: function(html){                
        $("#table_content").html(html); 
        clean_form();       
             }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: My retina literally burns each time I see people use code unaware of the vulnerability's to build into it. Yes, your code is liable to [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Please read the documentation on how to use prepared statements for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). If you don't, be prepared that 1 day your database is leaked to the web.

Comment: Simplify this problem to an ajax call. Everything else is irrelevant. Your relevant code starts around $.ajax. console.log(html) and what are you getting?

Comment: All i get when I use consol.log is index.php page when the comment/reply/ delete button pressed. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are basically trying to make ajax based comment system, From what i see, your code organization is not clear based on there tasks, specifically your index.php file so here is what you can do to simplify things :

1. your action.php should hanlde all php database releted tasks
2. Move your html code to some other file (Create Template)

Here is the modified code that i have come up with (This is just for your reference, you should modify this accoring to you needs, and as Xorifelse suggested in comment you should always use prepared statements in production system because of security concerns):

**Action.php**

```
<?php

include ("db_connect.php"); // Connecting to the database
$action = $_REQUEST['action']; 

if ($action=="add")
{
    $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
    $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
    $ParentId = $_REQUEST['ParentId'];


    $query="INSERT into `comments` VALUES (NULL,'{$ParentId}','{$user}','{$text}',NOW())";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}

if ($action=="delete")
{   
    $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
    $delete = "DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE id=$text";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$delete);
}

if ($action=="get")
{   
    $query="SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if (isset($_REQUEST['AnswerId']))
    { $AnswerId = $_REQUEST['AnswerId'];    }
    else
    { $AnswerId = 0; }

    $i=0;
    $mytable = array();
    while ($mytablerow = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $mytable[$i] = $mytablerow; 
        $i++;   
    }

    tree($mytable, 0, $AnswerId);
}

function tree($treeArray, $level, $ansId, $pid = 0) 
{
    $AnswerId = $ansId;

    if (! $treeArray) 
    { return; } 

    foreach($treeArray as $item){
        if ($item[1] == $pid)       
        {
            include('comments.template.php');
            tree($treeArray, $level+1,$AnswerId, $item[0]);   // Recursion
        }       
    }
}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="maker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadComments();">
        <div id="table_content">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**comments.template.php**

```
<div class="CommentWithReplyDiv" style="margin-left:<?php echo($level*60); ?>px">    
<div class="CommentDiv">
    <pre class="Message"><?php echo($item[3]) ; ?></pre>
    <div class="User"><?php echo($item[2]) ; ?></div>
    <div class="Date"><?php echo($item[4]) ; ?></div>
    <?php  
        if ($level<=4)  { 
            echo '<a href="javascript:" class="ReplyLink" onclick="AnswerComment('.$item[0].');">Reply</a>'; 
        }
        echo '<a href="javascript:" class="DeleteLink" onclick="DeleteComment('.$item[0].');">Delete</a>';
    ?> 
</div> 

<?php if ($AnswerId == $item[0]) { ?>
    <div id="InnerDiv"><?php  include('commentForm.template.php');  ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**commentForm.template.php**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden"  name="comment_on" id="comment_on"  readonly="readonly" value="<?php print md5($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" />
    <input id="user" name="user" value="name" autocomplete="off" onfocus="if(this.value == 'name'){this.value = ''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'name'}"/>               
    <textarea id='text' name='text' value="comment" onfocus="if(this.value == 'comment'){this.value = ''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'comment'}" ></Textarea>       
    <input id="ParentId" name="ParentId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($AnswerId);?>"/>
    <button type='button' OnClick="SendComment()">Comment</button>
</form>
```

**marker.js**

```
function DeleteComment(number){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",                  
        data: "user=1"+"&text="+number+"&ParentId=1"+"&action=delete",                  
        success: function(html){                        
            $("#table_content").html(html);  
            loadComments();       
        }
    });
}

function AnswerComment (id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",                   
        data: "AnswerId="+id+"&action=get",                   
        success: function(html){                        
            $("#table_content").html(html);             
        }
    });     
}

function SendComment (){
    var user1 = $("#user").val();
    var text1  = $("#text").val();  
    var ParentId1  = $("#ParentId").val() + ""; 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",  
        cache: false,       
        data: "user="+user1+"&text="+text1+"&ParentId="+ParentId1+"&action=add",        
        success: function(html){                
            $("#table_content").html(html); 
            loadComments();       
        }
    });
    return false;
}

function loadComments (){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "action.php",  
        cache: false,       
        data: "action=get",        
        success: function(html){                
            $("#table_content").html(html); 
            //clean_form();       
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. I followed your steps and it's work fine, But the only problem I'm having right now is to be able to reply, Earlier the reply button uses the:PHP(<?php function showForm($AnswerCommentId) { include('commentForm.Template.php');} ?>) and the ::HTML (
<!-- Reply --><a href="" id="L">comment</a>
<div id="Ma" style="display:none"><?php ShowForm(0);?></div>
<div id="AfterMainAnswerForm"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#L").click(function () {
  $("#InnerDiv").remove();
  $("#Ma").slideToggle("normal");
  return false;
    });
});
</script>)

Comment: You should also convert it to ajax, same as i have created loadcomments function, you should create loadform function (in javascript) and call it on comment click event.